Proof that $n! = \prod_{i=1}^n (n+1-i)$ using mathematical induction
Let $0<n$.
For $n=1$,
\begin{align*}
          n! &= \prod_{i=1}^n i\\
          &= 1 \\
         & = n + 1 - 1 \\
          &= \prod_{i=1}^n (n+1-i)
        \end{align*}
For some $k\in \mathbb{N}$, let $$k! = \prod_{i=1}^k k+1-i$$
Note that:
\begin{align*}
(k+1)! &= (k+1)k!\\
&= (k+1) \prod_{i=1}^k (k+1-i)\\
&= \text{What happens here?}\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^k \bigg((k+1)+1-i\bigg)\\
&= \bigg((k+1)+1-(k+1)\bigg) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^k \bigg((k+1)+1-i\bigg)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{k+1} \bigg((k+1)+1-i\bigg)
\end{align*}
I can't justify why $(k+1) \prod_{i=1}^k (k+1-i) = \prod_{i=1}^k \bigg((k+1)+1-i\bigg)$.

I think it may be clearer if you change the variable: let $j=k-i$ and see what happen to $j$ when $i$ ranges from $1$ to $k$.


$$(k+1) \prod_{i=1}^k (k+1-i) = \prod_{i=1}^k \bigg((k+1)+1-i\bigg)$$

This equality is fairly obvious if the products are written explicitly:
$$\begin{align*}
(k+1) \color{blue}{\prod_{i=1}^k (k+1-i)}
&= (k+1) \cdot \color{blue}{\underbrace{k}_{i=1} \cdot \underbrace{(k-1)}_{i=2} \cdot \underbrace{(k-2)}_{i=3} \cdot \ldots \cdot \underbrace{2}_{i=k-1} \cdot \underbrace{1}_{i=k}} \\
\prod_{i=1}^k \bigg((k+1)+1-i\bigg)
&= \underbrace{(k+1)}_{i=1} \cdot 
\underbrace{k}_{i=2} \cdot 
\underbrace{(k-1)}_{i=3} \cdot 
\ldots \cdot
\underbrace{3}_{i=k-1} \cdot 
\underbrace{2}_{i=k} 
\end{align*}$$
